# Remove Duplicate Lines From Text File?

Tags: c#, duplicates

Given an input file of text lines, I want duplicate lines to be identified and removed. Please show a simple snippet of C# that accomplishes this.

Comment: There are various methods, some easier to implement than others. The approach to be taken  can depend on the size of the text file and the expected number of matching lines. Can you describe the specific problem you're trying to solve? Thanks :)

Comment: . . . and the desired performance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do (and will copy with large files).

Note that it only removes duplicate *consecutive* lines, i.e.

```
a
b
b
c
b
d
```

will end up as

```
a
b
c
b
d
```

If you want no duplicates anywhere, you'll need to keep a set of lines you've already seen.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class DeDuper
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length != 2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Usage: DeDuper <input file> <output file>");
            return;
        }
        using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(args[0]))
        using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(args[1]))
        {
            string currentLine;
            string lastLine = null;

            while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (currentLine != lastLine)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(currentLine);
                    lastLine = currentLine;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this assumes `Encoding.UTF8`, and that you want to use files. It's easy to generalize as a method though:

```
static void CopyLinesRemovingConsecutiveDupes
    (TextReader reader, TextWriter writer)
{
    string currentLine;
    string lastLine = null;

    while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (currentLine != lastLine)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(currentLine);
            lastLine = currentLine;
        }
    }
}
```

(Note that that doesn't close anything - the caller should do that.)

Here's a version that will remove *all* duplicates, rather than just consecutive ones:

```
static void CopyLinesRemovingAllDupes(TextReader reader, TextWriter writer)
{
    string currentLine;
    HashSet<string> previousLines = new HashSet<string>();

    while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Add returns true if it was actually added,
        // false if it was already there
        if (previousLines.Add(currentLine))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(currentLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40):

For small files:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("filename.txt");
File.WriteAllLines("filename.txt", lines.Distinct().ToArray());
```

Comment: It looks like Distinct uses an internal Set class which appears to be a parred down HashSet class. Provided 'lines' isn't terribly large w.r.t. memory this should perform very well.

Answer (score 3):

For a long file (and non consecutive duplications) I'd copy the files line by line building a hash // position lookup table as I went.

As each line is copied check for the hashed value, if there is a collision double check that the line is the same and move to the next. (

Only worth it for fairly large files though.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a streaming approach that should incur less overhead than reading all unique strings into memory.

```
    var sr = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@"C:\Temp\in.txt"));
    var sw = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite(@"C:\Temp\out.txt"));
    var lines = new HashSet<int>();
    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        int hc = line.GetHashCode();
        if(lines.Contains(hc))
            continue;

        lines.Add(hc);
        sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
    sw.Flush();
    sw.Close();
    sr.Close();
```

Comment: It requires less memory, but it also produces incorrect output if there's a hash collision.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to .net & have written something more simpler,may not be very efficient.Please fill free to share your thoughts.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] emp_names = File.ReadAllLines("D:\\Employee Names.txt");
        List<string> newemp1 = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < emp_names.Length; i++)
        {
            newemp1.Add(emp_names[i]);  //passing data to newemp1 from emp_names
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < emp_names.Length; i++)
        {
            List<string> temp = new List<string>();
            int duplicate_count = 0;

            for (int j = newemp1.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (emp_names[i] != newemp1[j])  //checking for duplicate records
                    temp.Add(newemp1[j]);
                else
                {
                    duplicate_count++;
                    if (duplicate_count == 1)
                        temp.Add(emp_names[i]);
                }
            }
            newemp1 = temp;
        }
        string[] newemp = newemp1.ToArray();  //assigning into a string array
        Array.Sort(newemp);
        File.WriteAllLines("D:\\Employee Names.txt", newemp); //now writing the data to a text file
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: One thought: it'd be useful if you could comment your code to explain what you're doing (and why) - that'll help others understand your methodology and apply it to their situations in future.