# Checking a File for matches

Tags: c#, duplicates, match, streamwriter

I am saving each line in a list to the end of a file...

But would I would like to do is check if that file already contains that line so it does not save the same line twice.

So before using `StreamWriter` to write the file I want to check ***each*** item in the list to see if it exists in the file. If it does, I want to remove it from the list before using `StreamWriter`.

..... Unless of course there is a better way to go about doing this?

Comment: Is there a maximum number of lines, or is it completely open ended and the file can grow arbitrarily?

Comment: @Neil Fenwick: It is open ended :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your files are small and you are limited to flat files plus a database table is not an option, etc., then you could just read existing items into a list then make the write operation condition based on examining the list... Again, I would try for another method if at all possible (db table, etc) but just the most direct answer your question...

```
string line = "your line to append";

// Read existing lines into list
List<string> existItems = new List<string>();
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            existItems.Add(sr.ReadLine());

// Conditional write new line to file
if (existItems.Contains(line))
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path))
        sw.WriteLine(line);
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you could do is initialize the list from the file, adding each line as a new entry to the list.

Then, as you add to the list, check to see if it contains the line already.

```
    List<string> l = new List<string>{"A", "B", "C"};  //This would be initialized from the file.
    string s;
    if(!l.Contains(s))
        l.Add(s);
```

When you are ready to save the file, just write out what is in the list.

Comment: What if the file is 10's or 100's of MB?

Answer (score 0):

This will be slow, especially if you have a lot of data going into the table.

If possible, can you store all the lines in a database table with a primary key on the text column?  Then add if the column value does not exist, and when you're done, dump the table to a text file?  I think that's what I'd do.

I'd like to point out I don't think this is ideal, but it should be fairly performant (Using mssql syntax):

```
create table foo (
    rowdata varchar(1000) primary key
    );

-- for insertion (where @rowdata is new text line):

insert into foo (rowdata)
select @rowdata
where not exists(select 1 from foo where rowdata = @rowdata)

-- for output
select rowdata from foo;
```

Comment: So you would check one of the columns in the text to see if that column already exists? Could you explain a bit more what you mean? Maybe pseudo-code/code to help demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

If you can sort the file every time you save it would be much faster to determine if a particular entry exists.

Also a database table would be a good idea as mentioned earlier as you can search for the entry to be added in the table and if it does not exist add it.

It depends on if you are after speed (db), fast implementation (file access) or don't care (use in memory lists until the file gets too big and burns and crashes.)

A similar case can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245500/c-remove-duplicate-lines-from-text-file)