# Optimize Duplicate file entry Removal method

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code to optimize. As I expect the file to be large, I did not use a HashMap to store the lines but opted instead for a String array. I tried testing the logic with n of about 500,000 and it ran for approximately 14 minutes. I would definitely like to make it a lot faster than that and would appreciate any help or suggestions.

```
         public static void RemoveDuplicateEntriesinFile(string filepath)
        {
              if (filepath == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Please provide a valid FilePath");
              String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
              for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
              {
                    for (int j = (i + 1); j < lines.Length; j++)
                    {
                          if ((lines[i] !=null) && (lines[j]!=null) && lines[i].Equals(lines[j]))
                          {//replace duplicates with null
                                lines[j] = null;
                          }
                    }
              }

              File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);
        }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Jon Skeet already answered this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245500/c-sharp-remove-duplicate-lines-from-text-file

Comment: Wow after reading how complex that answer is I have to wonder if mine will even work, it is far simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“As I expect the file to be large, I did not use a HashMap to store the lines but opted instead for a String array.”

I don’t agree with your reasoning; the larger the file, the more of a performance benefit you’ll get from hashing. In your code, you’re comparing each lines with *all* succeeding lines, requiring O(n²) computational complexity for the whole file.

On the other hand, if you were to use an efficient hashing algorithm, then each hash lookup would complete in O(1); the computational complexity of processing your entire file becomes O(n).

Try using a `HashSet<string>` and observe the difference in the processing time:

```
public static void RemoveDuplicateEntriesinFile(string filepath)
{
    if (filepath == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("Please provide a valid FilePath");

    HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>(File.ReadLines(filepath));
    File.WriteAllLines(filepath, hashSet);
}
```

**Edit**: Could you try the following version of the algorithm and check how long it takes? It’s optimized to minimize memory consumption:

```
HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm = new SHA256Managed();
HashSet<string> hashSet = new HashSet<string>();
string tempFilePath = filepath + ".tmp";

using (var fs = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(filepath))
    {
        byte[] lineBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(line);
        byte[] hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(lineBytes);
        string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

        if (hashSet.Add(hash))
            sw.WriteLine(line);
    }
}

File.Delete(filepath);
File.Move(tempFilePath, filepath);
```

Comment: I am currently running the code to find out how much better than mine it is. :)

Comment: Turns out the above is not so much better than mine really. I tested it and it came back with Time Elapsed = 32.14.838245. Approximately the same time as my original code really. Any Ideas how I can make it even faster?

Comment: 14 minutes is way too long in any case. I just tested the performance of `HashSet<string>` on 500,000 random GUIDs (of 36 characters each), and it completed in less than a second. Your issue might be one of I/O.

Comment: There are variable number of characters on each line actually.

Comment: @user272671: How large is the file then (in bytes)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by creating a new list and adding to it.

```
        public static void RemoveDuplicateEntriesinFile(string filepath)
        {
              if (filepath == null)
                    throw new ArgumentException("Please provide a valid FilePath");
              String[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
              List<String> newLines=new List<String>()
              foreach (string s in lines)
              {
                   if (newLines.Contains(s)
                   continue;
                   newLines.add(s);
              }
              //not sure if you can do this with a list, might have to convert back to array
              File.WriteAllLines(filepath, newLines);
        }
```

Comment: You will have to run a test to see if it is actually optimized, but I think it will because you iterated through the list to the power of 2, which would be crazy with 500 000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

`lines[j] = null;` didn't work for me. `File.WriteAllLines(filepath, lines);` writes those lines as "" (string.Empty)