# C# removing duplicate from large text files

Tags: c#, file

I have a C# application which, amongst other things, needs to remove duplicate rows, and append a count of how many times that row occurs onto the end of the row.

The files can be extremely large, and from my perspective I cannot assume any limit to the size of the file.

There for it seems the best way for me to work with this file is line by line.

Removing the duplicates is fine - I have the following (from this question [Remove Duplicate Lines From Text File?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245500/remove-duplicate-lines-from-text-file)):

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(newFilePath))
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(aggregateFilePathBase))
{
    string currentLine;
    var previousLines = new HashSet<string>();              

    while ((currentLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (previousLines.Add(currentLine))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(currentLine);
        }
        else
            duplicateArray.Add(currentLine);
    }
}
```

My issue is that I can easily identify and remove the duplicates, but appending the count is proving problematic. As you can see, I have an array that is keeping a list of all duplicates. I can then use this to get the duplicates and generate the new row, like this:

```
if (duplicateArray.Count() > 0)
{               
    var duplicateGroups = duplicateArray.GroupBy(x => x);
    foreach (var duplicate in duplicateGroups)
    {
        var duplicateCount = duplicate.Count() + 1;
        var newLine = duplicate.First() + "," + duplicateCount;                 
    }
}
```

The problem is writing the count to file.
I could re run the read/write process, but my issue is that based on some calculations for a file with 150m rows, this write will take 30 hours+. So under this circumstance, it will take 60 hours to remove the duplicates.

Can anyone suggest a faster way.

I assume reading the whole file into memory and doing a find and replace is not an option as the file will be too big to load into memory...

EDIT:
From thinking about this more, I think I may also come into problems with the HashSet as this is effectively going to mirror the size of the file so will be limited to 2GB - is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps write a placeholder count "00000" to the file during creation, and remember the location in the file of that count so you can go back and update it using Seek(). As long as the placeholder count has enough digits to hold the maximum count, it should work. The final counts could have leading zeros if needed, or you could overwrite the extra ones with spaces as needed - but either way you'd have to write the correct number of characters when updating.

Comment: Is a `Dictionary<string, int>` not more convenient: If the line does not exist, add it to the dictionary. If it does exist, increase the value. The amount of duplicates can directly read out and you can replace the `previousLines` and `duplicateArray` by this Dictionary. (It will also be size efficient since only one copy of each duplicate is stored in memory instead of all of the lines).

Comment: What about a _map/reduce_ based approach? Like, splitting the file into digestible chunks and reducing into pairs [line, numberMatches]?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo that is what I am going to do

Comment: @Peter Duniho can you please advise why you put this question on hold? It seems to me the question is perfectly clear. Can you advise exactly what is wrong with it?

Comment: @EJoshuaS can you please advise why you put this question on hold? It seems to me the question is perfectly clear. Can you advise exactly what is wrong with it?

Comment: @Sangwin Gawande can you please advise why you put this question on hold? It seems to me the question is perfectly clear. Can you advise exactly what is wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

SQLite is great for this.  Insert each line as a value in the db, then do a `group by` query with a count to return a recordset containing distinct lines and a count of the times they appear.  Doing all the inserts in a single transaction turns out to be blazing fast.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
```

...

```
using (var myconnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;"))
using (var fileLineReader = new StreamReader(newFilePath))
{
    myconnection.Open();
    var cmd = myconnection.CreateCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "drop table if exists myfile";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd.CommandText = "create table myfile (value varchar(2147483647))";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    using (var transaction = myconnection.BeginTransaction())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into myfile (value) values (@value)";

        string line;
        while ((line = fileLineReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", line);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }

    cmd.CommandText = "select value,count(*) as count from myfile group by value";

    using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText(aggregateFilePathBase))
    {
        foreach (IDataRecord record in cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            writer.WriteLine(record["value"] + "," + record["count"]);
        }
    }
}
```